# In python what's the fastest way to generate the tuple: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, ..., N, 0.0, 0.0)?

Tags: python, tuples

Looking for the fastest way of generating a tuple with the pattern mentioned in the title, i.e:

```
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, ..., N, 0.0, 0.0)
```

for any positive N that respects: `round(N) == N`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fastest I can come up with off-hand is using `itertools` functions to push all the work to the C layer:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

def make_tuple(N):
    return return tuple(chain.from_iterable(zip(map(float, range(1, round(N)+1)), repeat(0.0), repeat(0.0))))
```

`repeat` makes the zeroes, `map(float, range(1, round(N)+1))` makes the non-zero values, `zip`ing them together makes three-`tuple`s which `chain.from_iterable` flattens so `tuple` constructs the final result directly.

While it does involve temporary three-`tuple`s (unlike [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54818851/364696)), on the CPython reference interpreter it doesn't actually create new `tuple`s at all; `zip` is optimized to reuse the `tuple` from the last result for the new result if no other references to the `tuple` exist when the next value is requested (and `chain.from_iterable` is releasing its reference each time).

For comparison with other answers, `ipython` microbenchmarks for `N` of 150:

```
>>> %timeit -r5 make_tuple(150)
28.1 µs ± 1.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit -r5 make_tuple_tim_peters(150)
17.1 µs ± 52 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> %timeit -r5 make_tuple_julien(150)
154 µs ± 1.85 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit -r5 tuple(values_patrick_haugh(150))  # Modified to convert to float properly
40.7 µs ± 1.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I tried a few other approaches similar to my own approach above with listcomps and genexprs myself, but none of them got below 40 µs, so I didn't bother to post them.

[Tim Peter's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54818853/364696) is definitely the fastest posted so far, and unlikely to be bettered. As [he notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54818775/in-python-whats-the-fastest-way-to-generate-the-tuple-1-0-0-0-0-0-2-0-0-0/54818854#comment96413494_54818853), it's a little more memory hungry, since at peak memory usage it needs storage for the whole result `tuple` and the temporary `list` (though each should be exactly sized, with no overallocation), meaning the peak memory for the containers is roughly twice what is "needed". Mine does require `tuple` to overallocate as it goes (since it doesn't know how large the result will be), which in current CPython, as an implementation detail, means overallocation of around 25%. A savings, but not a significant one; if performance mattered, I'd almost always go with Tim's solution.

Later update: I did eventually manage to find something that beats Tim's answer, but only by resorting to `numpy`, and the incremental improvement is pretty trivial:

```
from numpy import arange, zeros

def make_tuple_numpy(N):
    ret = zeros(3*round(N))
    ret[::3] = arange(1., N+1.)
    return tuple(ret.tolist())
```

It's basically the same as Tim's answer, it just uses `numpy` to do the work with raw C primitive types in bulk (e.g. `np.arange` directly produces a range in floating point form without creating a bunch of Python `int`s only to convert them to `float`s), uses the `tolist` method to have `numpy` perform the conversion to `list` without a Python iterator getting involved, then wraps in the `tuple` constructor (which special cases `list`, so again no iterator involvement). Even with all that, the advantage is pretty trivial:

```
>>> %timeit -r5 make_tuple_numpy(150)
13.8 µs ± 158 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

It's a further reduction in runtime of ~20% vs. Tim's solution, but unless you're doing this a *lot*, the cost of importing `numpy` probably eliminates the savings.

Comment: Unless, of course,  numpy is required by the enclosing code. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Who knows? ;-)  In CPython, "the trick" usually involves avoiding explicit Python-level loops, and in avoiding quadratic-time catenations.  Here's one way:

```
def gentup(N):
    NI = round(N)
    assert N == NI
    result = [0.] * (3 * NI)
    result[::3] = map(float, range(1, NI + 1))
    return tuple(result)
```

Then, e.g.,

```
>>> gentup(4)
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

All the real work runs "at C speed" then, and even `float` is looked up only once (despite being *invoked* `round(N)` times).

Comment: Ooh, nice. Beats [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54818854/364696), which was already pretty good (yours runs in about 60% of the time of mine).

Comment: Ya, "the problem" with itertools-heavy approaches to things like this is that -  alas - it takes actual time to resume an iterator over and over.  It adds up.  The thing I posted gets all the zeroes essentially for free, and they make up 2/3rds of the result.  Turns out it's cheaper to mutate a list to replace the other 1/3rd, then copy the whole thing into a distinct tuple.  Yours is more frugal with memory, though, which can matter if `N` is on the order of billions ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't doubt it. I just sometimes forget a one-liner isn't *always* the best solution. :-) As soon as I saw your code I suspected it would beat mine, precisely because of the overhead (however tiny) of advancing the `repeat` iterators and `zip` the results. I added precise numbers to my answer just for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that doesn't generate any temporary tuples.

```
def values(N):
    nums = range(1, N+1)
    for n in nums:
        yield n
        yield 0
        yield 0

print(tuple(values(5)))
# (1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Minor tweak required to match OP: Change `nums = range(1, N+1)` to `nums = map(float, range(1, round(N)+1))` so it rounds the input and converts the values to `float`, and change each `yield 0` to `yield 0.` or `yield 0.0` to make the zeroes `float` as well.